# UIInterfaceOrientation not rotating to correct orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

I am presenting different UIViewController over another ViewController like this

```
    [_presentingViewController presentViewController:_backgroundViewController animated:NO completion:^{
       //present another view controller
    }];
```

Sometimes the orientation between the presented ViewController and the presenting ViewController changes which is managed in the ViewControllers like this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Normally that works fine but every once in a while it looks like in the picture below. When I then rotate the device in my hand it flips to the correct layout. But at first it is rendered wrongly.
I handle the chaining of presentation and dismissing always in the completion handlers.

The strange thing is that I cannot reproduce it. It just happens very rarely on both the device and the Simulator.

[image: Wrong orientation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is some issue with "Requires Fullscreen". Since I activated it it did not occur again.

[image]